# Getting Secrets From Azure (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I’m trying to do a personal project and I want to use either Azure Key Vault or the appsettings that the Azure Web Apps provide by default. But I have only one concern. I guess if I want to use these, I still need to store some sensitive information, like TenantId, ClientId, ClientSecret, or Thumbprint if I use certificate.

If I use secrets.json then in development I’m fine, but if I publish it to the control version the application won’t work without these sensitive information, right? And in the appsettings.json I wouldn’t use them, because I don't want them to get pushed to the source control with the file.

What are your thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Expected outcome:
I want to get the sensitive data from either Azure Key Vault or Azure Web App appsettings, but without using any sensitive data in appsettings.json.
(I think (Azure) TenantId, ClientId, ClientSecret, Thumbprint are sensitive enough, but please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Can't you use [managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) instead?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that it even exists. I will check it out soon and let you know if this is it I searched for. But based on what it is, it looks promising. :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @PeterBons @MattDouhan and @AlexeiLevenkov probably I need the Managed Identities :) Thank you guys for the quick help, I will mark the question resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Key Vault Secrets to store the following kind of values
a.  SQL Conn String
b.      Relay Conn String
c.  Client ID (Service Principal)
d.  Client Secret (Service Principal Pwd)
e.  Any other sensitive values which are not supposed to be disclosed to developers.

Comment: difficult to stop a dev from reading the config entry and dumping it to log or console though, better to use Managed Identities for this purpose since there is nothing to dump

Comment: This does not answer OP's question on how to actually access Key Vault - indeed you can store secrets there, but to read it one needs some sort of secret to start with (or using managed identity as @MattDouhan pointed out

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).